# Calculating Percentage in XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have my XML -

```
<FS>
    <Percent>0,00</Percent>     
    <Amount ACI="US">3212,62</Amount>
</FS>
```

I want to consider both elements and calculate percentage with  & 
with my XSL 1.0

How can this help -

```
<xsl:variable name="Discount" select="Percent"/>
<xsl:variable name="Amount" select="Amount"/>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($Discount div 100 * $Amount)"/>
```

This is giving me NaN value. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the value coming in XML which consists of Comma (,). It needs to be translated to Dot(.) first and then calculation can be done.

```
<xsl:variable name="Discount" select="translate(Percent,',','.')"/>
<xsl:variable name="Amount" select="translate(Amount,',','.')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($Discount div 100 * $Amount)"/>
```

This will generate the desired results.

Comment: The normalize-space call is unnecessary. The result of a multiplication will never contain spaces.